# dask: how to groupby, aggregate without losing column used for groupby

Tags: python, group-by, dask

How do one get a SQL-style grouped output when grouping following data:

```
   item   frequency
    A      5
    A      9
    B      2
    B      4
    C      6

df.groupby(by = ["item"]).sum()
```

results in this:

```
  item   frequency
    A      14
    B      6
    C      6
```

In pandas it is achieved by setting `as_index=False`. But dask doesn't [support this argument in groupby](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.groupby). It currently omits `item` column and returns the series with `frequency` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps call `.reset_index` afterwards?

Comment: Thanks. `reset_index` works. If you have the info, can you also explain how scalable `reset_index` is?

Comment: It's embarrassingly parallel, so very scalable